# Spark reduce function is causing "error type mismatch"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to scala - spark and loaded my dataset in RDD . here is my sample data set

```
scala> flightdata.collect
res39: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((DFW,11956), (DTW,588), (SEA,607), (JFK,1595), (SJC,327), (ORD,4664), (PHX,4993), (STL,661),
```

from the above dataset , i need to find total sum . Hence i written like this

```
scala> flightdata.values.sum
res40: Double = 445827.0

scala> flightdata.map(_._2).reduce( (a,b) => a + b)
res41: Int = 445827
```

Both value.sum and map using reduce is giving the right answer. But i am trying to rewrite the same code tuple with reduce.

```
scala> flightdata.reduce( (s1,s2) => s1._2 + s2._2)
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: (String, Int)
       flightdata.reduce( (s1,s2) => s1._2 + s2._2)
```

it is causing error. type mismatch. why it is causing type mismatch error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you try to combine two tuples, but have integer as result.

You should return tuple `("", s1._2 + s2._2)` instead of `s1._2 + s2._2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. After replacing to "("", s1._2 + s2._2)" expression it is working fine. In reduce fn. Input type is same as output type. is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. You have pair of "something" and should return one "something"